# Multivariable calculus over polar regions - Calculate range

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this question I have to solve. see the image below:
[image]

The calculus bit itself, I know I have to use polar coordinates to solve it. But I can't seem to figure how to find the range of beta in the questions first part. It feels like I am missing something really simple here.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome. $(x+\beta y)^2=\color{red }{x^2+2\beta  xy}+\beta^2y^2$. Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clarify the question a bit to make it clear.

- You have for each $\beta \in \Bbb R$, a real function of two real variables:$$F_{\beta}:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$$ $$(x,y)\mapsto x^2+2\beta xy+y^2$$ that the questioner simply notes $F$.
- For example, consider the case of $$F_{-1}:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$$ $$(x,y)\mapsto x^2-2xy+y^2=(x-y)^ 2$$ We immediately see that $\beta_0=-1$ does not belong to the range of $\beta$ so that $\color{blue}{\forall (x,y)\neq (0,0), F_{\beta}(x,y)>0(*)}$, since for example $F_{-1}(7,7)=0$.
- $\forall \beta \in \Bbb R, F_{\beta}(0,0)=0$

Then let's use the important trick I gave you in the comments : $$\forall x,y,\beta \in \Bbb R,\color{green}{(x+\beta y)^2}=\color{red }{x^2+2\beta  xy}\color{green}{+\beta^2y^2} $$
Then $\color{red}{x^2+2\beta xy}+y^2=\color{green}{(x+\beta y)^2-\beta^2y^2}+1y^2$

Then, $$F_{\beta}(x,y)=(x+\beta y)^2+(1-\beta^2)y^2(**)$$
For example, $\forall (\beta,y )\in \Bbb R\times \Bbb R^*, F_{\beta}(0,y)=y^2>0$, what we see even better on the starting formula but whatever.

Let $y_0\in \Bbb R^*$ and $x_0=-\beta y_0$ (so that $x_0+\beta y_0=0)$

$F_{\beta}(x_0,y_0)=F_{\beta}(-\beta y_0,y_0)=(1-\beta^2)y_0^2$

So, if you want $\color{blue}{(*)}$, necessarily, $1-\beta^2>0$, i.e. $\beta \in (-1,1)$.

Conversely, according to $(**)$, any $\beta \in (-1,1)$ is fine. The range sought is $(-1,1)$.